# Jslint claims variable is already defined? (1)

Tags: javascript, jslint

```
function wrapper() {
    var $R = {};

    $R.expandFont = function (direction, max_time) {
        // wtf? $R jslint error
        var self = this,
            el_prim = self[0],
            $R = {};

        alert(direction + max_time + el_prim + $R);
    };
}
```

This snippet gives error:

```
line 573 character 13
'$R' is already defined.
```

I think it is clear that it has not been previously defined.

$R was defined in the outer scope, but this should not be relevant.  I should be able to define a local variable with the same name as JavaScript ( the language ) is function scoped.  Yes, I know it is not block-scoped, but it is function scoped.

It is basic scoping rules.  What gives?

Is this a jslint bug?

Comment: Are you using prototype.js? It defines $R.  What happens if you omit this code and type $R in the console?

Comment: It doesn't give me that result when I run that code through JS Lint.

Comment: To successfully set $R.something = function(){...}; $R has to be defined.

Comment: it might be because you are sawing off the limb you are sitting on...

Comment: @WilliamTweed — You want me to copy the code *from your question* into JS Fiddle so that you can then copy it into JSLint? Just copy it from your question directly.

Comment: @WilliamTweed — Presumably, when you created your reduced test case, you reduced it so far that the problem you described went away.

Comment: @dandavis No, you are creating a new limb, and hiding the old one until you return to the previous scope.

Comment: @Paul: i didn't get the error, so it was a stab; looking closer i can see you're right. in my defense, it's very confusing having "this", "self", and "$R" all refer to the same thing...

Comment: @dandavis I agree, and I also don't torture myself with jslint, so probably shouldn't bother looking at this either :-)

Comment: self is a used keyword, not a great idea to re-define it in general as it makes code less readable. i see "self", i think "window". duplicating global names as different locals also makes for less readable code. i think the fact it tricked me is evidence of that notion; i'm no fool... on the other point, if you did not have the "var $R", $R would be this. depending on hoisting also makes code less readable. in short, valid code!= clean code.

Comment: The problem is only apparent when the declaration in the outer scope occurs *within a function*. This is likely why people have been unable to reproduce it. See my answer for details.

Comment: [James'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17852430/1028230) is a great answer.  Here's a [lintable pastebin reproducing the problem with the OP's code](http://pastebin.com/32GFZWL0).  I'll try to submit an edit with it. Comes down to a typical Crockfordian subjectivity battle -- He tries to avoid code that looks like an error, and the OP feels this usage "should not be relevant".  Using JSLint makes you consistent, which is good, but makes you consistent with Crockford's own opinions, which makes many bristle.  It is an ego-checking experience, but makes for better code..

Comment: I like jslint b.c. it takes things that are style or opinion choices and forces you to use one way all the time.  It's not the choice of `a` or `b` that matters but the fact that you are now more self aware and always do `a` when it does not matter FUNCTIONALLY either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a new feature in JSLint. It was added by [a commit](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/3d6c7b974efc7be3b1c2e5a6dedac6a9d70dad47) on 24 July 2013. The following example demonstrates the cause of the error:

```
(function () {
    var a = 1; // This declaration...
    return function () {
        var a = 2; // ... is shadowed by this one.
    };
}());
```

It appears that the warning is only issued when JSLint encounters a variable declared *in function scope* (not in the global scope) that is later shadowed (which may explain why commenters on your question were unable to reproduce it).

It appears that currently there is *no way* to turn off this warning.

Crockford has [the following to say](https://plus.google.com/u/0/118095276221607585885/posts/2JY9bjaup1g) about this new warning:

> JSLint now warns when a var is defined that has the same name as something in the outer scope. This is confusing because the reader cannot easily tell which variable he is looking at. It is sometimes an error because the new variable is accidentally hiding the old one. In some cases, the old one is the one intended.

I will get a page fully explaining this up on http://jslinterrors.com as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: @WilliamTweed - Agreed, it could make the code less readable, but I disagree with the decision to not make this an *opt-in* feature. At the moment you can't even opt-out of it. In your case, if you know `$R` is not going to be needed in descendant scopes, then there is no issue with it whatsoever.

Comment: For those looking to turn off warning, I found that using the option shadow = true will turn off the warning.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your understand yourself, that if you rename `$R` in outer or in inner scope of the function the JSLint "error" will be fixed.

I decided to write my answer only because I think there are misunderstanding about *the goal of JSLint*. It's not just a tool which helps you to find errors from the point of view of JavaScript language. You can consider the tool as AddOn to the book [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742). Douglas Crockford tried to show **which constructions of the language could be misunderstood by people which read the code**. Some from the potential misunderstandings he declared as "warnings", another as "errors". Some from the "warnings" or "errors" can be suppressed by comments like `/*jslint ... */` another not (like declaration of `var` inside of for-loop header). The choice which potential misunderstandings should be interpret as a "warning" and which one as an "error" is *very subjective* and represents only the personal meaning of Douglas Crockford.

I'm not always agree with recommendations of Douglas Crockford, but the warning ("error"): `'$R' is already defined` I would personally find also as critical because of difficulties to read such code. I would recommend you to rename one from `$R` variables too. I want to emphasize one more time that **the goal of such changes not fixing of an JavaScript error, but improving of readability of your program for other people**.

By the way I would recommend you to use variables with all capital letters only on the top level (`$R` looks so, independent from the first `$` letter). See the last sentence of [the JSLint recommendation about the naming convention](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#names).

Answer (score 1):

```
line 573 character 13
'$R' is already defined
```

This is because $R is already defined.  Two options:

Change the variable name

Or change your code to this:

```
var $R = {};

$R.expandFont = function (direction, max_time) {
    // wtf? $R jslint error
    var self = this,
        el_prim = self[0];

    $R = {};
```

Also, see this post by DC on [redefinition](https://plus.google.com/118095276221607585885/posts/2JY9bjaup1g).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously,

`$R` is causing confusion.  To the jslint syntax analyzer and the the members of SO.  Change it, when you move from outer scope to inner scope.

From `$R` to something like `$PR`, or other.

There is no need to cause this confusion, when you could simply change the variable name.

Crockford is no fool.  These are good guidelines should you choose to follow them.