# Is JSHint "is already defined" errors inside of IIFE modules really valid?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint, module-pattern, iife

I took the output of some compiled TypeScript (also tried with CoffeeScript) and put it into WebStorm.  When I do, JSHint complains "'Snake' is already defined" for the inner declaration of the Snake function.

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var Animal = (function () {
    function Animal(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    Animal.prototype.move = function (meters) {
        alert(this.name + " moved " + meters + "m.");
    };
    return Animal;
})();

var Snake = (function (_super) { 
    __extends(Snake, _super);
    function Snake(name) { //Warning registered here
        _super.call(this, name);
    }
    Snake.prototype.move = function () {
        alert("Slithering...");
        _super.prototype.move.call(this, 5);
    };
    return Snake;
})(Animal);
```

I can disable the warning with `/*jshint -W004 */`, but it seems like the warning is invalid since we are scoped within a function.

Now the weird part. If I move the `__extends` call down to after the function declaration, the error disappears.

```
function Snake(name) {
    _super.call(this, name);
}
__extends(Snake, _super);
```

I really have 2 questions, but the first is my main question which I will award my answer to.

1. Is this warning valid?
2. What are the ramifications of moving the `__extends` call down below the function declaration?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it might be complaining because the inner variable is shadowing an outer variable of the same name which could be potentially confusing.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17852430/378151

According to this other SO answer, a commit was made in July 2013 around this behavior. [Douglas Crockford stated](https://plus.google.com/u/0/118095276221607585885/posts/2JY9bjaup1g) (about JSLint)

> JSLint now warns when a var is defined that has the same name as
>   something in the outer scope. This is confusing because the reader
>   cannot easily tell which variable he is looking at. It is sometimes an
>   error because the new variable is accidentally hiding the old one. In
>   some cases, the old one is the one intended.